# Facebook Client-side authentication and offline_access deprecation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

Before you start yelling at me, I know many users already asked for something like this, but I read all of them and couldn't find any reply related to my specific case: I eventually managed to get something working but it's not what I think I (and other developers) are looking for. I want to share my experience about this with all of you, so I'll try and describe my scenario and the steps I followed to look into how to take care of this, so please indulge me for this long post: I'm sure it will help some developers in the same situation as I am to clear their minds too, just as I hope it will give others the right information to help me (and others) with it.

I wrote a native Android application that makes use of the Facebook API. I **DO NOT** make use of the Facebook SDK, because I don't want to rely on the official app being installed on the device (as a matter of fact, my app is in part an alternative to that app so it would be silly to need it installed anyway in the first place), but I rather issue Graph API calls directly via HTTP and handle the responses myself. So if that is the answer you're thinking of giving me, please don't because I won't take that road.

As such, I made use of the Client-side authentication to authorize my app, displaying the URL in a WebView and getting the access_token at the end. I requested offline_access among the other permissions.

Since offline_access is going to be deprecated in May, I started investigating how to get long lived tokens anyway, and so read almost everything I could find related to that, including of course the official guidelines. Long story short, nothing worked for me, and I'm still stuck with very short-lived access_tokens that I can do nothing about.

This is what I did to begin:

1. Deprecated the offline_access for my app (well not **THE** app since it's being used by many users right now, but another one which is basically the same and I use for testing purposes only so that's the same thing) in the settings.
2. Authorized a user using Client-side authentication: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://my.domain.com/yeah.htmlscope=publish_stream,read_stream,user_photos,friends_photos,offline_access&response_type=token&display=wap

I got my access_token, but I immediately noticed how it was not long-lived at all, quite the opposite: expires_in was set to something like 6800 seconds (less than two hours). So the first assumption I had made (access_tokens will be longer lived by default) was already wrong.

I looked into how this access_token lifetime could be extended then, and tried almost every alternative out there. Needless to say, every attempt failed. That's what I tried, to be precise:

1. First of all, I of course tried the "official" approach, that is extending the token through the new endpoint. Skipping for now the rant about how stupid it is to request the client secret for such an operation (as many folks already pointed out, such secret would need to be embedded in the Android app, which is a security nightmare as far as we developers are concerned, and moving this bit server-side to extend the token life on behalf of the user is a nightmare for what concerns them instead, since they'd need to trust me with messing with their access_token), I tried issuing a GET request to that address using the correct parameters: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN ...The request was apparently successful, but it did **NOT** extend the lifetime of anything. The request just returned the same access_token as before, with an expires_in parameter that just reflected the sand of time flowing away (the same as before minus the seconds passed since I authorized). Basically, that method only told me how much the already available access_token would live, without refreshing or changing anything, so, despite the obvious security concerns it raises, it is pretty useless too.
2. I then tried what someone else suggested, that is using the old REST API to do the job, issuing a GET request to the following address: https://api.facebook.com/method/auth.extendSSOAccessToken?access_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN which obviously failed too with the infamous "The access token was not obtained using single sign-on" error.

After those failed attempte, I started thinking about what may be the cause of all of them failing. As I anticipated, my app runs on Android devices but makes triggers HTTP requests to the API directly, which I guess may be the root of the problem.

1. In the advanced section of my developer apps page, my app was configured as "Web" rather than "Native/Desktop". That said, changing it to "Native/Desktop" did nothing but give me a longer-lived access_token at the first logout (about 24 hours rather than 1-2), while the already described attempts at extending its life failed just as before.
2. The official guideline has an interesting and quite creepy paragraph: "Desktop applications will not be able to extend the life of an existing access_token and the user must login to facebook once the token has expired". While this seems to have been overlooked by many, I started to think this may be the cause of my problems, so I tried an alternative approach, that is, I tried the server-side authentication rather than the client side one: again, this requires client_secret so would be a dumb solution for an Android app but I wanted to try that anyway. So, I got the code first, and then the access_token after that (as described in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/). This resulted in a much longer lived access_token (5183882 seconds, that is about 59 days), but then again, both the known means for extending it (even if not really needed in this case) resulted in the same thing: the former not refreshing anything, the latter complaining about the fact it was not obtained via SSO.

So, **very** long story short (I know, too late), the deadline for deprecating offline_access is so close you can feel it breathing on your neck, and nothing seems to work. What is your experience with all of this and, if you're on the same boat as I am and you managed to get it working, how did you do it?

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Since the deadline for that deprecation has been pushed back to October now, I'm guessing to address some of these issues, have you managed to resolve this quandary in the mean time?

Comment: I have the exact same concerns. :'(

Comment: I eventually integrated the server-side extension mechanism. I don't know if it really is doing anyting (my app still requests offline_access), but the plan was to put it there so that it would take care of extending the token as soon as the breaking change kicked in. I'm probably going to face bitter disappointment, but I'll only know in a few days I guess :)